# Requests library not working? Nothing appears in console

Tags: python, python-requests, console

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import tkinter as tk


class Scraping:

    @classmethod
    def get_to_site(cls, stock_name):
        sitename = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/' + stock_name
        site = requests.get(f'{sitename}')
        print(site.status_code)
        

    def get_price():
        pass


class GUI:
    pass

Scraping.get_to_site('tsla')
```

So I'm doing an app that should take stock prices from a site and show them graphically. I had barely started when a problem occured. I tried to  print the status code of my requests site to check if it finds the right site. When I run this, nothing appears to the console.
Console looks like this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Aatu\Documents\python\pythonleikit> & C:/Python39ni/python.exe c:/Users/Aatu/Documents/python/pythonleikit/stock_price_scraper.py
```

I've waited for a long time to have something appearing in the console but nothing happened. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these headers to your request will do the trick.

```
class Scraping:

    @classmethod
    def get_to_site(cls, stock_name):
        sitename = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/' + stock_name
        
        site = requests.get(sitename, headers={
            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language":"en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,ml;q=0.7",
            "Connection":"keep-alive",
            "Host":"www.nasdaq.com",
            "Referer":"http://www.nasdaq.com",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36"
        })
        
        print(site.status_code)
        

    def get_price():
        pass


class GUI:
    pass

Scraping.get_to_site('TSLA')
```

Comment: Thank you alot! It's working although I have no clue what those headers are doing, I would be grateful if somebody explained a bit about those.

Comment: The header contains information of the client in this case, and what it expects or demands the server to respond.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header